# How to setup conditional relationship on Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationships

I have this (simplified) table structure:

```
users
- id
- type (institutions or agents)

institutions_profile
- id
- user_id
- name

agents_profile
- id
- user_id
- name
```

And I need to create a `profile` relationship on the `Users` model, but the following doesn't work:

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function profile()
    {
        if ($this->$type === 'agents')
            return $this->hasOne('AgentProfile');
        else
            return $this->hasOne('InstitutionProfile');
    }    
}
```

How could I achieve something like that?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Lets take a different approach in solving your problem. First lets setup relationship for the various models respectively.

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function agentProfile()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(AgentProfile::class);
    }    

    public function institutionProfile()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(InstitutionProfile::class);
    }

    public function schoolProfile()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(SchoolProfile::class);
    }

    public function academyProfile()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(AcademyProfile::class);
    }

    // create scope to select the profile that you want
    // you can even pass the type as a second argument to the 
    // scope if you want
    public function scopeProfile($query)
    {
        return $query
              ->when($this->type === 'agents',function($q){
                  return $q->with('agentProfile');
             })
             ->when($this->type === 'school',function($q){
                  return $q->with('schoolProfile');
             })
             ->when($this->type === 'academy',function($q){
                  return $q->with('academyProfile');
             },function($q){
                 return $q->with('institutionProfile');
             });
    }
}
```

Now you can access your profile like this

```
User::profile()->first();
```

This should give you the right profile. Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm not sure this applies. I need to be able to eager load the profile and access $user->profile->name.

Comment: Check the scope well. It is eager loading the profile(base on the type) and am using **with** to eager load which is more efficient preventing any N+1 query problems. i have changed your if statement to a more laravel like eloquent syntax

Comment: Yes, you're right. But what if I have more profile types?

Comment: Have updated the answer. You can use if statement if you feel more convenient with that.

Comment: Seems perfect. Thank you!

Comment: Help me, I use it for my code, but, always returns the relation 'user_share', even when type is 1...

Comment: This will not work due to the "user" object not being loaded when the scope runs. Thus "$this->type" will always be null when loading the user. You would have to first load the user and only *then* run the rest of the code.

Comment: @AndreiGabreanu, what do you mean by loading the user first? I'm getting null on "$this->type".

Comment: its giving me $this->type as null how did you guys solve the proble

Comment: Without eager loading possibility this is not the right answer

Answer (score 6):

you can do this by use another method please check this:

> a blog Post and Video model could share a polymorphic relation to a
>   Tag model. Using a many-to-many polymorphic relation allows you to
>   have a single list of unique tags that are shared across blog posts
>   and videos. First, let's examine the table structure:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations

Comment: Thanks, but polymorphic relations doesn't apply here.

Comment: I think polymorphic is right here, but you need to restructure your database slightly.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that should be `$this->type` rather than `$this->$type` - since `type` is a property, not a variable.

Comment: I just can't believe I didn't see that! Thanks.
But now I'm getting this error when trying to eager load the profile: 

`Fatal error:  Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on a non-object in /vendor/illuminate/database/Eloquent/Builder.php on line 667`

Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure exactly what might cause that - maybe check the names of the tables/models? I noticed they're called different things so they might need `$table` properties in their respective models.

Comment: Have just seen that message about `addEagerConstraints` - this is caused when your relationship function (e.g `profile()`) doesn't return anything - suspect a scope is the better way to go.