# How to return all models in BelongsToMany relationship

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I have relationship on `User` model like below:

```
public function brands() {
    $roles = config('constants.roles');

    if ($this->hasRole($roles['brand_site_admin'])) {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Brand::class, 'brand_has_users');
    } else 
    if ($this->hasRole($roles['client_admin'])) {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Brand::class, 'brand_has_client_admin');
    }

    // For admin role I want to return all brands, from Brand Model
    // ?? 
}
```

For Admin role I want to return all rows from `Brand` model, How can I get that?
And that should be instance of `BelongsToMany` class,  then only it won't break code in my controller.

### Update:

When I do `$user->brands()` I want all the brands from `brands` table if `$user` is an admin (In above code if it doesn't goes in any condition then it's Admin).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this as suggested in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43668153/how-to-setup-conditional-relationship-on-eloquent), first create the relationships like this

```
    $roles = config('constants.roles');
public function siteAdminBrands()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Brand::class, 'brand_has_users');
    }    

    public function clientAdminBrands()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Brand::class, 'brand_has_client_admin');
    }

    public function brands($query)
    {
        return $query
              ->when($this->hasRole($roles['brand_site_admin']),function($q){
                  return $q->with('siteAdminBrands');
             })
             ->when($this->hasRole($roles['client_admin']),function($q){
                  return $q->with('clientAdminBrands');
             });

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I think you didn't get the question.

Comment: yeah I haven't it exactly I just make an assumption please make it clear so that I can try to help you :)

Comment: what you have tried share your query you have tried to get the result may be that will clear the things

Comment: When I do `$user->brands()` I want all the brands from brands table if `$user` is an admin.

Comment: ok and what are you currently getting if you type `$user->brands()`??

Comment: Respective brands for other roles. Not for admin. See updated question.

Comment: hey check the answer i have updated it and let me if it doesn't work

Comment: In this scope works on `user` model, so `user->brands()` returns users, not brands.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154351/discussion-between-mr-pyramid-and-shyammakwana-me).

Comment: ok then use hasMany in place of belongsToMany as it has inverse relationship.

Comment: Not yet, I've researched something but didn't worked

Comment: Mm.. ok bro! :)