# how to have multiple author type for model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i hope you can help guys.

i have a table called `services`, a service can have one author but can be of type `organization` or `user`
these are the tables i have:

1- services:

```
id  author_id  content
```

2- authors:

```
id  author_id author_type
```

3- users

```
id  email username
```

4- organizations:

```
id  about
```

how do i get the  organization or user for the service as a Model?

Comment: What relationships have you already defined in your models?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir they are not related except for `user()` on `service`, and i need to replace it later with `profile()`, cuz i found the solution on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50865204/how-to-have-multiple-author-type-for-model/50866375?noredirect=1#comment88735491_50866375,

Answer (score 0):

To get the `user` (and assuming that you need to keep the `author` and `user` tables separate, although it looks like merging them may be best), create a one-to-one relationship between `author` and `user` and a one-to-many relationship between `author` and `service`, then use dynamic properties to access the `user` model.

**Author.php**

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\User');
}

public function services()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Service');
}
```

**User.php**

```
public function author()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Author');
}
```

**Service.php**

```
public function author()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Author');
}
```

You should then be able to access the user of a service using the dynamic property `author`, like so.

```
$myService->author->user
```

**You will need to define an `author_id` on your `user` table for this to work.**

*Getting the `organization` of a `service` will work similarly.*

This section of the Laravel documentation should help if you have additional questions: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one

**Note:** This will work for you current table structure, but is very round-about and repetitive. You should consider merging your `user` and `author` tables to de-duplicate data and simplify your model relationships.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help but i'm not looking to access the `author` model, i'm looking to access the 'user' model through 'author', i was able to join them but still the result is instance of 'App\Author', i know it's hard to get the desired result, but i'm hoping if there is a way

Comment: thanks a lot i think this might work for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43668153/how-to-setup-conditional-relationship-on-eloquent

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is achieveable. You will simple use the Morph relation

**service model**

```
/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphTo
 */
public function author()
{
    return $this->morphTo('author');
}
```

And both your user.php and Organaztion.php models need to have the following:

```
/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphMany
 */
public function services()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Services', 'author');
}
```

Then you can get the author of the service like so:

```
// will return a user or organization object depending on the author_type
dd($service->author);
```

Or you can get the services for a user or organization

```
$user->services();

$organization->services();
```

**Polymorphic relations**: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations

Comment: yep i'm already testing this method, i tested few but this gonna be the last one, will see how it goes