# Use a model type to fetch another table based on its table

Tags: php, laravel

I have a `Todo` and this `Todo` can have a `SubTodo`. Each `SubTodo` can be of the following types:

- text
- dropdown
- boolean

Each of these `SubTodo` have specifics that is related to each one of its type so I resolved to separated into its own table. The database table structure is as follow:

```
todo
- id

sub_todo
- id
- todo_id
- type [dropdown, text, boolean]

sub_todo_dropdown
- id
- sub_todo_id

sub_todo_text
- id
- sub_todo_id

sub_todo_boolean
- id
- sub_todo_id
```

A `SubTodo` needs to have a relationship called `meta` that will resolve the fields that is specific to which type. I have defined the following relationship:

**Models/SubTodo.php**

```
// The SubTodo will have meta information on other tables
// that will be depending on the type of the SubTodo.
// To fetch those meta information's we will
// have this set where will map the
// relationship to its model
const META_MODELS = [
    self::SUB_TODO_TYPE_TEXT => SubTodoText::class,
    self::SUB_TODO_TYPE_BOOLEAN => SubTodoBoolean::class,
    self::SUB_TODO_TYPE_DROPDOWN => SubTodoDropdown::class,
];

public function meta(): HasOne
{
    return $this->hasOne(self::META_MODELS[$this->type], 'sub_todo_id');
}
```

But when I try to load this relationship with

```
$subTodos = SubTodo::with('meta')->paginate();
```

I get `"message": "Undefined index: "`. After doing

```
public function meta(): HasOne
{
    dd($this->type);
    return $this->hasOne(self::META_MODELS[$this->type], 'sub_todo_id');
}
```

I get `null`. My best guess is that the model wasn't loaded yet so I need to load the model first and then call `meta`:

```
$subTodos = SubTodo::limit(10)->get()->each(function (SubTodo $subtodo) {
   $subtodo->load('meta');
});
```

But this approach will cause a `N+1` problem. Is there any way I can achieve to load `meta` without having to load all models first? Is this a good usage for [one to one polymorphic relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one-polymorphic-relations)?

Comment: Do you need to maintain the three different tables or it can be done within one table? If your answer is with one table, you can use query scope.

Comment: For better maintanability into the future this needs to be three different tables. For example, the `dropdown` type has a `dropdown` attached to it while a `text` type doesn't have a `dropdown` attached to it.

Comment: how you are setting $this->type ? Through any constructor or any setter or default property value?

Comment: the `$this->type` is an attribute of the model. It comes directly from the migrations

Comment: I am afraid you are maybe missing the $this->type at self::META_MODELS[$this->type]. There might a case it only works for any of the three value in the META_MODELS array and getting null for the other two

Comment: Please check this out, maybe your answer is here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43668153/how-to-setup-conditional-relationship-on-eloquent

Comment: @TohidDadashnezhad That approach makes you load first the `User` model and then eager load the resource creating `N+1` problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I think there is no way except overriding the Model.

- 1 Create the `SubTodoBuilder` class:

  ```
  <?php


  namespace App\Builder;


  use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

  class SubTodoBuilder extends Builder
  {
    const RELATIONS = [
       "text" => "SubTodoText",
       "boolean" => "SubTodoBoolean",
       "dropdown" => "SubTodoDropdown"
    ];

   /**
    * Eager load the relationships for the models.
    *
    * @param array $models
    * @return array
    */
   public function eagerLoadRelations(array $models): array
   {
       foreach ($this->eagerLoad as $name => $constraints) {
           if ($name === "meta") {
               $groupedModels = collect($models)->groupBy("type");
               $models = [];
               foreach ($groupedModels as $type => $subModels) {
                   $relation = self::RELATIONS[$type];
                   $result = $this->eagerLoadRelation($subModels->all(), $relation, $constraints);
                   $models = array_merge($models, $result);
               }
           }
           //This part may need some modification
           if (strpos($name, '.') === false && $name !== "meta") {
               $models = $this->eagerLoadRelation($models, $name, $constraints);
           }
       }
       return $models;
   }
  }
  ```
- 2 In `SubTodo` model:

  ```
  <?php

   namespace App\Models;

   use App\Builder\SubTodoBuilder;
   use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
   use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
   use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
   use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne;

   class SubTodo extends Model
   {
     use HasFactory;


     protected $fillable = [
         "todo_id",
         "type"
     ];

     public function SubTodoText(): HasOne
     {
         return $this->hasOne(SubTodoText::class);
     }

     public function SubTodoDropDown(): HasOne
     {
         return $this->hasOne(SubTodoDropdown::class);
     }

     public function SubTodoBoolean(): HasOne
     {
         return $this->hasOne(SubTodoBoolean::class);
     }

     public function meta(): HasOne
     {
         return $this->hasOne("meta");
     }

     /**
      * Create a new Eloquent query builder for the model.
      *
      * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder  $query
      * @return Builder|static
      */
     public function newEloquentBuilder($query)
     {
         return new SubTodoBuilder($query);
     }
  ```

  }
- 3 In your controller

  ```
  public function index()
  {
     $subTodos=SubTodo::with("meta")->get();
  }
  ```

Now if you have 30 `SubTodo` to fetch and each 10 `SubTodo` has one of the three types, it will execute 1+3 queries.